# LISP Loop For Returns NIL

Tags: loops, for-loop, return, lisp, common-lisp

I have this small program that prints triangles either forwards or backwards depending on whether the input is positive or negative. It works perfectly, except at the end of every loop it prints NIL. I tried changing the bounds of the loop, but every when I do it effects the size of the triangle. Is there any solution to this? Please find the code below.

```
(defun triangle(k) 
    (cond ((or(not(integerp k)) (= k 0)) '("invalid number; please enter a positive or a negative integer"))
          ((< k -1) 
             (loop for x from k to -1 do
                 (loop for y from k to -1 do 
                       (if (< y x) 
                           (princ #\Space)
                           (princ '*) 
                       ) 
                     
                  ) 
                (terpri)
              )
          )  
        
         ((or (= k 1) (= k -1)) '*) 
         (t(loop  for x from 0 to k do 
               (loop for y from 0 to k do  
                 (if (< x y)    
                     (princ '*) 
                 )
                ) 
                (terpri)
           ) 
         ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: The REPL prints the value returned by the function. Since the function doesn't return anything explicitly, it returns `NIL` by default.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what your function does. You can just ignore it.

Comment: is there any way to remove it at all? like how would I change the implementation so i does not return nill?

Comment: Try returning `(VALUES)` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Barmar I am still getting nil if I do this. Perhaps I am not implementing it correctly. Here is a snippet of code where I added (VALUES) `(t(loop  for x from 0 to k do 
               (loop for y from 0 to k do  
                 (if (< x y)    
                     (princ '*) 
                 )
                ) 
                (terpri)
           )  
            (VALUES)
         )  `

Comment: I think you're stuck with it, that's what you get in the REPL. It has to print something.

Comment: read-eval-print always prints something.

Comment: `(values)` should be before the very last `)`.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right, even putting the (values) right before the last bracket, it still returns null. Thank you for all the suggestions though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The lack of proper formatting of your code is making the code unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun triangle (k) 
  (cond ((or (not (integerp k))
             (= k 0))
         '("invalid number; please enter a positive or a negative integer"))
        ((< k -1) 
         (loop for x from k to -1 do
               (loop for y from k to -1 do 
                     (if (< y x) 
                         (princ #\Space)
                       (princ '*))) 
                (terpri)))
        ((or (= k 1) (= k -1))
         '*) 
        (t
         (loop for x from 0 to k do 
               (loop for y from 0 to k do  
                     (if (< x y)    
                         (princ '*))) 
               (terpri))))
  (values))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 8 > (triangle 3)
***
**
*


CL-USER 9 >
```

Comment: I still receive NIL at the end of this when I put `(print (triangle 3))`

Comment: @abdcg: why would you PRINT the result of a call to triangle? The function triangle already itself prints the triangle -> you are calling the functions PRINC and TERPRI inside TRIANGLE.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly now, did not think about that!

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is off topic, considering your question was about loops, but i would propose to separate data generation, manipulation and representation, which is always a good practice. You could make a single triangle generator, and then invert it, if needed. It could look like this, for example:

```
(defun mk-tri (n)
  (when (plusp n)
    (loop for i from 1 to n
          collect (nconc (loop repeat i collect #\*)
                         (loop repeat (- n i) collect #\space)))))

(defun print-field (field)
  (format t "~{~{~a~}~%~}" field))

(print-field (mk-tri 5))
;; *    
;; **   
;; ***  
;; **** 
;; *****

(defun invert-v (data)
  (reverse data))

(print-field (invert-v (mk-tri 5)))
;; *****
;; **** 
;; ***  
;; **   
;; *    

(defun invert-h (data)
  (mapcar #'reverse data))

(print-field (invert-h (mk-tri 5)))
;;     *
;;    **
;;   ***
;;  ****
;; *****
```

this would give you the whole new level of freedom, like you can imagine this little toolkit for patterns drawing:

```
(defun concat-v (d1 d2)
  (append d1 d2))

(defun concat-h (d1 d2)
  (mapcar #'append d1 d2))

(defun repeat-v (n data)
  (reduce #'concat-v (loop repeat n collect data)))

(defun repeat-h (n data)
  (reduce #'concat-h (loop repeat n collect data)))

(let* ((tri (mk-tri 5))
       (tri2 (concat-v tri (invert-v tri)))
       (rect (concat-h tri2 (invert-h tri2))))
  (print-field (repeat-v 2 (repeat-h 3 rect))))
;; *        **        **        *
;; **      ****      ****      **
;; ***    ******    ******    ***
;; ****  ********  ********  ****
;; ******************************
;; ******************************
;; ****  ********  ********  ****
;; ***    ******    ******    ***
;; **      ****      ****      **
;; *        **        **        *
;; *        **        **        *
;; **      ****      ****      **
;; ***    ******    ******    ***
;; ****  ********  ********  ****
;; ******************************
;; ******************************
;; ****  ********  ********  ****
;; ***    ******    ******    ***
;; **      ****      ****      **
;; *        **        **        *
```